# Stored procedure output using sp_executesql returning null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-executesql

I'm using the below procedure taking table name, schema name and database name dynamically to generate a `SELECT` statement. When I execute this stored procedure without assigning `@select_statementOUT` anywhere, it works fine.

However, the `OUTPUT` value in `@select_statement` is returned as NULL. I want the `@select_statement` variable to return the output string. I'm not sure where to put the `@select_statementOUT` so that it fetches me the string.

This is the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selectTableAttributes
    @database_name Nvarchar(255),
    @schema_name Nvarchar(255),
    @table_name Nvarchar(255),
    @select_statement nvarchar(MAX) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query1 nvarchar(MAX), @query2 nvarchar(MAX), 
            @query3 nvarchar(MAX), @query4 nvarchar(MAX), 
            @querydb nvarchar(MAX), @query nvarchar(MAX)

    SET @querydb = N'USE ' + @database_name
```

I tried assigning `@select_statementOUT` below which is throwing an error - Incorrect syntax near 'sql_statement' & Incorrect syntax near 'tbl_custom_data'

```
    SET @query1 = N' Select @select_statementOUT =
concat(''select case when count(*) > 100 then ''''transaction'''' else  ''''reference'''' end as cloud_content_type, min('',
case when cloud_transaction_column is not null then cloud_transaction_column
else ''1'' end,'')  as cloud_transaction_start_date,'',
char(39),
case when cloud_transaction_column is not null then cloud_transaction_column
else ''1'' end,
char(39),
'' as cloud_transaction_column,'',
char(39),
cloud_load_type,
char(39),
'' as cloud_load_type,'',
char(39),
table_type,
char(39),
''as table_type '',
'' from '', tbl_details) sql_statement '


    SET @query2 = N'From (Select
tbl_details,
cloud_transaction_column,
case ............ continued .....................................
where  col.table_name=''' + @table_name

    SET @query3 = N'''
and col.TABLE_SCHEMA=''' + @schema_name

    SET @query4 = N'''
) tbl_columns
where cloud_transaction_seq is not null
group by tbl_details)
Tbl_col_group
) tbl_final_data
) tbl_custom_data'

    SET @query = @querydb + @query1 + @query2 + @query3 + @query4

    EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@database_name Nvarchar(255),
                                 @schema_name Nvarchar(255),
                                 @table_name Nvarchar(255),
                                 @select_statementOUT nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT',
                      @database_name, @schema_name,
                      @table_name,  
                      @select_statementOUT = @select_statement OUTPUT

END
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the dynamic SQL statement where you are assigning the `@select_statementOUT` output parameter. Try `SET @query1 = N' Select @select_statementOUT = ...'`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried that. It's giving me an error - Incorrect syntax near 'sql_statement'.

Comment: My suggestion was a general one since I can't run your script without the underlying tables and data to see the proper placement. If you need help tweaking the query to assign the `@select_statementOUT` parameter value, post the value of the `@query` parameter passed to `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Re: `Incorrect syntax near 'sql_statement'`, I have only looked over it quick ly, but it appears as though you originally had `SELECT CONCAT() sql_statement`, using "sql_statement" as a column alias. Adding the variable assignment as suggested by Dan was correct, but that invalidates using a column alias. Just remove the `sql_statement` after the `)`. If that works, then @DanGuzman should post an answer as that was main issue.

Comment: @srutzky That worked perfect. Thank you.